# How to show webcam captured through CanvasFrame on scene in javafx

Tags: opencv, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder, javacv

I am working with opencv,javacv,javafx.

I want to show the captured webcam not on the CanvasFrame but on scene of my running application.
Here is the code of method which is capturing,

```
@FXML
void openWebcamOnBtnClick(ActionEvent event) 
{

    Thread thread=new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            //super.run(); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            opencv_highgui.CvCapture capture=opencv_highgui.cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
            opencv_highgui.cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, opencv_highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 360);
            opencv_highgui.cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, opencv_highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);

            opencv_core.IplImage grabbedImage=opencv_highgui.cvQueryFrame(capture);

            CanvasFrame frame=new CanvasFrame("Webcam");
            frame.setCanvasSize(640, 360);

            while(frame.isVisible() && (grabbedImage=opencv_highgui.cvQueryFrame(capture))!=null)
            {
                frame.showImage(grabbedImage);

            }


            opencv_highgui.cvReleaseCapture(capture);
            grabbedImage.release();
            //frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        }

    };

    thread.start();

}
```

By doing so , webcam starts capturing perfectly fine and shows it on CanvasFrame(On new Stage). but i want it to show on the old stage, whenever i click on the button "Open Webcam"" which is on the old stage.

Can i show the capturing webcam in ImageView or any pane??